# SSRS: Combobox of parameter's value not working in preview

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

This is the `Dataset` for the available values of the parameter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DateSaved
FROM         RB_Values
WHERE     (Cid = @cid)
```

And here are the Report Parameter Properties:

[image: properties1]

[image: properties2]

[image: properties3]

But as you can see here the `combobox` for `DateSaved` is not working:

[image: inputs]

What am I missing? How I can make the `combobox` to show DateSaved values?

Comment: There could be other issues but you have the default values set to the results of your dataset but you have not set your parameter to be multi-value. Also you need to check the date format of the results of your dataset.

Comment: Also, the ID parameter is not filled out so it needs that to return what you want I think

Comment: The dataset for the available values and default values depend on a parameter named `@cid`, so the query can only be processed after that parameter has a value. As soon as you have entered a feasible value for `@cid`, the *DateSaved* parameter will be enabled.